# Prove that $A$ is similar to $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial, similar-matrices

> Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ such that $m_A(x) = m_B(x)$ and $$f_A(x)=f_B(x)=(x-\lambda_1)^{d_1}\cdots (x-\lambda_k)^{d_k}$$ for different $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$ such that $1 \le d_l \le 3$ for all $1 \le l \le k$. Prove that $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices.

---

1. We can assume that $A,B$ are in **Jordan form** because $A_J \sim A \sim B \sim B_J$.
2. We also may assume $A,B$ are **Jordan blocks** of some $\lambda_i$, because if each $J_{A_i} \sim J_{B_i}$ (order doesn't matter) then $A\sim B$. (Right? I am not sure about it)
3. So now we're looking at $A, B$ two jordan blocks. We know that $$m_A(x) = m_B(x) = (x-\lambda_i)^{d'_i}$$ and $1 \le d'_i \le d_i \le 3$.

What do I do now?

Comment: So $m_A$ is the minimal polynomial for $A$ and $f_A$ is the characteristic polynomial for $A$?

Comment: Yes. Common notations I think

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you @Kimball.

Comment: I've edited the third assumption.

Comment: Sorry, ignore that comment.  Can you prove this in the 2x2 case?

Comment: @AlonAlon $p_A$ (char) and $q_A$ (min) are more commonly used in my experience.  Also, $\chi_A$ (for char) in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $d_i \leq 3$, then $d_i'$, the degree of $(x - \lambda_i)$ in the minimal polynomial, which is the size of the largest Jordan block associated with $\lambda$, completely determines the Jordan form of the $\lambda$-blocks up to similarity.

If $d_i = 1$, there is one Jordan block of size $1$.

If $d_i = 2$, then if $d_i' = 2$, there is one Jordan block (of size 2). If $d_i' = 1$, there are two (of size 1).

If $d_i = 3$, then if $d_i' = 3$, there is one Jordan block (of size 3).  If $d_i' = 2$, then there is one Jordan block of size 2, and the other Jordan block must then have size $1$.  If $d_i' = 1$, then all Jordan blocks are size $1$.